# Read first file in a list of files within a directory

Tags: files, ls, command

I wanted to read the first text file in every directory using "cat or vi". To clarify the issue:

The Folder_A1 contain 1000 text files. The files named in the following format "i.1351". All the files names starts with "i." and the number is different between these files.

I have 500 Folders, each one contain ~1000 text file (*.txt), and I want to read just the first file in each folder. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "first file"?

Comment: if you "cd"  the folder and run "ls ". I want to read the first file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the first file in directory order, and assuming all folder names start with `Folder_`, all entries starting with `Folder_` are directories, and all entries stating with `i.` are files:

```
for d in Folder_*; do
    for f in "$d"/i.*; do
        cat -- "$f"
        break
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit slow because of the sort.

```
find . -type f | sort -V | 
awk -F/ '{ dir=substr($0,1,length($0)-length($NF));
           if(last==dir)next; last=dir; print}' |
| xargs cat
```

The `-V` is to sort `i.2` before `i.10`. The `awk` prints the filename every time the directory changes. (Assumes names have no spaces in them.)